# How to monitor cloudwatch alarms in grafana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a panel in grafana to show cloudwatch alarms. I want the panel to be like a ticker or table with the latest alarm appearing on the top. I tried using cloudwatch datasource but I was not able to make it work. I am thinking of pulling the data from a postgres sql which can be filled when there is a new alarm (cloudwatch + sns + lambda). Is this the correct approach or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Cloudwatch alarms in Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952667/show-cloudwatch-alarms-in-grafana)