# Show Cloudwatch alarms in Grafana

Tags: amazon-sns, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to add a table that shows a list of AWS Cloudwatch alarms for a particular metric. I found this dashboard [AWS SNS](https://grafana.com/dashboards/581) but that just shows number of SNS messages sent. Is there any way of querying specific Cloudwatch alarms?

Answer (score 2):

No, current Grafana code and current CloudWatch API doesn't support it. Of course, you can code it on your own.

Comment: This is correct. Only the core data sources found in Grafana's code base has access to the `Grafana` alert component.

Comment: @samuel-toh I didn't ask about using Grafana alerts. Although I see worldping plugin offers alerts now so is that still true? https://grafana.com/plugins/raintank-worldping-app

Comment: @parsley72 world ping is a premium app owned by Grafana labs so I’m not surprise it can do grafana alerting. So my comment still holds true.

Comment: You are mixing "AWS Cloudwatch alarms" and "Grafana Alerts" in your comments. Question is about "AWS Cloudwatch alarms"